# retrofit returns null string

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get a string in a textview of my app, from the retrofit callback. I am using an android JSON data example and making a retrofit call to retrieve this data as a string. For some reason getting a null value response. Gradle and Manifest seem to be fine. Unfortunately didn't find answer in related topics. Will appreciate help.

API:

```
private const val BASE_URL =
    "https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()



private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface WordsApiService {
    @GET("realestate")
    fun getProperties():
            Call<List<MarsProperty>>
}

object WordsApi {
    val retrofitService : WordsApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(WordsApiService::class.java) }
}
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
class QuizWordListViewModel: ViewModel() {


    private var _response = String()

    val myWordsAsString
        get()=_response

    init {
        getWordsFromNet()
    }




    private fun getWordsFromNet():String {

        WordsApi.retrofitService.getProperties().enqueue(

            object: Callback<List<MarsProperty>> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<MarsProperty>>, response: Response<List<MarsProperty>>) {
                    _response = "Success: ${response.body()?.size} Words retrieved"
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MarsProperty>>, t: Throwable) {
                    _response = "Failure: " + t.message
                }
            })

        return _response
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY:

```
class QuizWordListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: QuizWordListViewModel
            by lazy {ViewModelProvider(this).get(QuizWordListViewModel::class.java) }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContentView(R.layout.quiz_word_list_activity)
        var testObject:TextView = testObject

        testObject.text = viewModel.myWordsAsString

    }


}
```

PROPERTY

```
data class MarsProperty(
    val id: String, @Json(name = "img_src") val imgSrcUrl: String,
    val type: String,
    val price: Double
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`realestate`](https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com/realestate) is a JSON response; better use the [`MoshiConverterFactory`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/converter-moshi/retrofit2/converter/moshi/MoshiConverterFactory.html) instead.

Comment: I implemented the moshiconverterfactory and the property. Problem remains the same. Could you inspect my Activity? It is started with the button pressed in the main activity.